# Operand Datatype nvarchar is invalid for avg operator

Tags: sql, t-sql, average, nvarchar

I need to find the average of this column named "Edges".
The kind of values in there are like follows: (NOTE: There are a bunch of **NULL** as well)

```
 EDGES
 1. 1,362,797
 2. 204,919 
 3. 26,138 948,570 
 4. 111,471 5,858
```

I have tried running the query to display non null values:

```
SELECT AVG(Edges) AS test from 
(SELECT [Edges] as Edges FROM dbo.tracker
WHERE [Edges] like '%[^0-9]%') as a
```

The error I get is this: " **Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for avg operator.** "

What is the query to average this column?

Comment: Looks like the data type for column `Edges` is string and not numeric. As the error message stated, "you can't use nvarchar for avg"

Comment: You can calculate the average of numbers (e.g. the average of 10 and 20 is 15), but not of strings (e.g. what would the average of 'dog' and 'cat' be?). While your string `'1,362,797'` could be converted into the number 1362797, you would have to tell the DBMS to do so. And `'26,138 948,570'` is not a number and can hence not even get converted. If this is supposed to be 26 billions and something, then there must be a comma where you have a blank.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes. StackOverflow edited my post. All values are just '26,138' and then the next row is '948,570'. I tried to use CAST and convert them to INT but it does not work. I need the average of that column. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: As you see it's a very bad idea to store numbers as strings. You should change your data model accordingly.

Then, you are looking for strings that contain non-digit characters. This seems weird. It means that from a list of values like

```
1,000
2,000
3000
4000
```

you will only consider those that have a thousand separator and get a result of (1000 + 2000 / 2) = 1500. (And there must be no strings in that table that have a non-digit character and don't represent a number, because then trying to calculate an average will fail utterly of course.)

Anyway, if you want this and as long as this is your data model, you will have to convert the strings to numbers. Unfortunately, SQL Server's type conversion features are very limited to say the least. The DBMS is supposed to be able to convert from string to number implicitly and this works:

```
select '948570' + 0;
```

but this fails:

```
select '948,570' + 0;
```

and this:

```
select '948,570' + 0.0;
```

and even this:

```
select '948570' + 0.0;
```

As thousand separators are mere beautifiers, your best bet is to remove them completely (with `REPLACE`) and convert explicitly. Be aware though, that SQL Server tends to use primary school integer math when it detects integers (e.g. 1 / 2 = 0, not 0.5). So in spite of your strings representing integers, convert them to DECIMAL, not INT.

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL, REPLACE(edges, ',', ''))) as avg_edges
FROM dbo.tracker
WHERE edges like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, e.avg_edges
from t cross apply
     (select avg(try_cast(s.value as numeric)) as avg_edges
      from string_split(t.edges, ',') s
     ) e;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08a3f506612fc558a0f150962bdfd092) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This ignores non-numeric values such as `138 948`.  But your question doesn't explain how to handle such values.

EDIT:

If you want the average across all the rows:

```
select avg(e.edge)
from t cross apply
     (select try_cast(s.value as numeric) as edge
      from string_split(t.edges, ',') s
     ) e;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this. I wanted to check the average of the entire column. Meaning I need just one value in the end as the average of 'edges'. The db<>fiddle shared shows averages for each. I am not sure how to work with that. Could you explain and solve this for me please?